# How do you find stats of a column chart in R?

Tags: r, geom-col

My dataset has 2 variables :

1)Match_City (name of the city where a soccer match is played)
2) Home_score (number of goals by the home team)

The problem is there more than 1500 cities and it's not possible to make out which cities have the highest total of Home_score. I want to know if I can get data of that column chart i.e. City A has a total of 20 goals from home team. I am currently using geom_col() to make the column chart. I need help!

Comment: Hi Ishwar, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data, for example with `dput(dataset[1:10,])`. Additionally it is not clear exactly what you hope to plot. Do you want to plot only cities with `Home_score > 20`? See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little difficult to understand your question and as others have noted you should try to give us a reproducible example with code.

However, if I understand your question correctly...

You have a large dataframe with two columns (Match_City and Home_score) and you have made a column chart to compare the totals of Home_score for each Match_City.

Now you can visually see which Match_City has the highest total Home_score but you would like R to calculate these numbers in a way that you can work with. The aggregate function is your best bet here.

Some example code:

```
#Let's Create Some Data

df <- data.frame(Match_City=sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 100, replace = TRUE), Home_score=sample(1:6, size = 100, replace = TRUE))

#Aggregate will find the sum of Home_score for each Match_City

score_summary<-aggregate(Home_score~Match_City, data = df, FUN = sum)

#You can then sort the score_summary data frame so that the Home_score sums are in decreasing order

score_summary<-score_summary[order(score_summary$Home_score, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. And I am really sorry that I didn't explain it well as I am new to Stack Overflow and even R. I was looking for this answer only. +1.

Comment: No problem. Our comments are to help you become a member of our community. I am glad the answer worked for you. Please accept the answer as correct and good luck learning R!